# # Evaluate accuracy. accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=get_test_inputs, steps=1)["accuracy"]

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the tensorflow [get started](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn)
we can see the code:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 # Evaluate accuracy.
  accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=get_test_inputs,
                                       steps=1)["accuracy"]

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to know what does the ["accuracy"] mean? i can't understand the format. It belong to the knowledge of python or tensorflow?

thx

Answer (score 0):

It will belong to Tensorflow or whatever other specific machine learning library you might use. Tensorflow has more about metrics and accuracy [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy). Evaluating accuracy can mean taking the prediction values for the test dataset (which was *never* in the training data, but that you *do* have the true labels for), and calculating the difference between the model predictions, and the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the return value of `estimator.Estimator.evaluate` is described as:

> A dict containing the evaluation metrics specified in model_fn keyed
>   by name, as well as an entry global_step which contains the value of
>   the global step for which this evaluation was performed.

In fact, that line simply applies  `dict.get("accuracy")`  to extract the value stored in `'accuracy'` field. It is a Pythonic knowledge. For further information on dictionaries and their keys, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey).

EDIT: Also you can simply execute the line in a Python interpreter without `['accuracy']` part. If you look the ingredients of `accuracy_score`, you will see that it is indeed a dictionary that contains key-value pairs.